# Insert to records with the same execute statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert to records with one execute statement but I am geting this error:

> your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO stops(name, route, lat, longi) values('XYZ alle', '9', '83.868863',' at line 1

```
    stt.execute("INSERT INTO stops(name, route, lat, longi) values('blabla', '1', '93.838039', '14.700440' );" 
+  "INSERT INTO stops(name, route, lat, longi) values('xyz', '9', '83.868863', '14.665438' );" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not you do multiple value inserts:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (field1, field2)
VALUES (val1, val2), (val3, val4), ...
```

Note the `(..),(..),...` construct.

You generally cannot execute more than one statement in a single query call using mysql.